# Matlab imshow() not showing the image properly

Tags: matlab

I have a simple code to show an image in Matlab. I use `imread()` to read it and `imshow()` to show it. the code it below, and the result in not shown properly. hope someone can help me.

```
img = imread('/home/samuelpedro/Desktop/API - Projecto/coimbra_aerea.jpg');
figure, imshow(img);
```

the resulting image is below.
[image]

also, if i choose to save it to file as a new jpg it is saved correctly.

UPDATE 1:

weirdly if i choose to show the axes in the preferences>image processing, it is corrected

Comment: fix the image link please, or explain what not showing properly.

Comment: @natan Download the link and add .png as the extension to file. The problem looks like it is tiling the picture over and over.

Comment: thanks SamuelNLP, can you please add the jpg file too, so we'll be able to replicate this beautiful and weird bug...

Comment: @SamuelNLP: Is the problem that the image is tiled? Otherwise, everything looks fine to me.

Comment: @Jonas yes the image is tiled. repeating over and over.

Comment: @SamuelNLP: can you upload the original jpeg? I never had that problem before.

Comment: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v706/joao74/coimbra/coimbra14a.jpg

Comment: @Jonas weirdly if i choose to show the axes in the preferences>image processing, it is corrected

Comment: @SamuelNLP: have you changed the renderer to see if it's a OpenGL problem? `set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer')`, for example

Comment: @Jonas I haven't change anything.

Comment: @SamuelNLP: I just meant it as a suggestion: change renderer, see whether the problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locking at your screen-shot, the x- and y-ticks are missing. They should appear in a standard-configuration of Matlab. Maybe something is just messed up in the Matlab-configuration. Try to do this with a clean new `~/.matlab` folder (rename the old one before).

Alternatively ... again judging by your screen-shot, this looks like Ubuntu/Unity in the background. Unity needs acceleration (OpenGL), which can be randomly buggy for some Linux graphics drivers. You may want to try to launch matlab in a "clean" X-server (maybe the twm environment) to rule this out.

Save the image as an (uncompressed) bitmap (bmp) and read it with imread. If the jpg is messed up by the imread-routine, this should rule this out.

Last but not least, broken copy of your jpg on your disk, some flipped bits. Run md5sums on your file's copies.

Comment: weirdly if i choose to show the axes in the preferences>image processing, it is corrected